Errors with MS Word's Revisions Object in VBA
I've checked posts like this about Word's Revisions object, but haven't seen anything about this "unplanned feature" from our friends in Redmond.
When I iterate the Revisions collection, I run into a Revision object that is "deleted" and it appears to corrupt the rest of the collection.
My code:
Sub TestRevs()
    Dim lRev&, oRev As Revision, lNdx&, oRevs As Revisions
    
    
    On Error GoTo oops
    If mDoc Is Nothing Then Set mDoc = ActiveDocument
    
    Set oRevs = mDoc.Revisions
    On Error GoTo oops
    
    For lRev = 1 To oRevs.Count
        Set oRev = oRevs(lRev)
        lNdx = oRev.Index
        Debug.Print lRev, lNdx
skip:
    
        DoEvents
    Next lRev

finish:
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

oops:
    
    If Err.Number = 5852 Then
        Resume skip
    Else
        Debug.Assert False
        Resume
    End If
    
End Sub

What happens is it gets to a Revision object that returns <This object has been deleted>, and every subsequent Revision object in the collection that is not also "deleted" is the exact same Revision as the last one before the first "deleted" revision. In my example, #18 is deleted, so every subsequent non-deleted Revision has identical properties to #17, as shown in the output:
lRev          oRev.Index
 1             1 
 2             2 
 3             3 
 4             4 
 5             5 
 6             6 
 7             7 
 8             8 
 9             9 
 10            10 
 11            11 
 12            12 
 13            13 
 14            14 
 15            15 
 16            16 
 17            17 
 19            17 
 21            17 
 23            17 
 25            17 
 27            17 
 29            17 

Any help is welcome; I appreciate your attention!!
UPDATES:
Responding to comments:
"Deleted objects": mDoc.Revisions is the collection of all the individual changes tracked. The loop iterates each element of the collection and assigns them to oRev. MSWord generates the collection. In this example, when i=18, oRev=oRevs(18), and the oRev object (per the "locals" pane of the VBE) shows that oRev contains a "deleted object" by showing all the properties are <This object has been deleted>, and attempting to retrieve any property results in a run-time error. Not sure how else to explain it.
Steps:
Open a document that either has changes tracked, or turn on "Track Changes" and make a few edits, then run the code. The Revisions object should be a collection of all the individual changes that have been tracked, and a single Revision object is the details about one specific change. No real "steps" to take other than run the code on a document with some changes that have been tracked?

"a Revision object that returns " do you mean a piece of text which has been deleted?  Exactly where are you seeing that message?  When you get that output, has the code entered the error handler during its execution?

Please outline some steps for us to be able to test your code and reproduce the error.

I ran your code in a test document with some edits (after removing all the error handling) and the output didn't show any issues (and no run-time errors)

Of course it didn't, @TimWilliams! ... the car never acts up for the mechanic!! :)  I guess I'll have to dig into the XML to see what's going on with the document, itself. I appreciate your efforts. If I find something, I'll circle back here.

There's maybe something very specific going on in your document which I'm not replicating.

Can we assume that iterating in reverse order doesn't improve anything?

You are correct; reversing the order does not help. The last of 5000 changes still has oRev.Index = 17
